# How I can fill an entrybox in tkinter from another gui

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I import a function named "select_date". This function runs a gui application (calendar-datepicker) and returns the selected year, month and day (the function is well tested).
I want to fill the tkinter entry with the selected date. When I run the code the entry is not filled. However, when instead of using the select_date function to get the date we use a defined value e.g. date="yyyy/mm/dd" (commented in the code), the program runs as expected and the entry is filled with "yyyy/mm/dd".

```
import Tkinter as tk
from mycalendar import select_date


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("My App")
root.geometry("400x400")
w = tk.Label(root, text="Aerosol Optical Depth & Trends")
w.grid(column = 0, row = 100)
w.pack()

# ~ date="yyyy/mm/dd"

e = tk.Entry()
e.pack()

e.delete(0, tk.END)

year,month,day=select_date(myinput="From Date")
date=str(year)+'/'+str(month)+'/'+str(day)

e.insert(0, date)

root.mainloop()
```

The select_date is in the following code:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

import datetime
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
import tkMessageBox



def select_date(myinput):

    def example1():
        def print_sel():
            print(cal.selection_get())
            global year
            global month
            global day
            year=cal.selection_get().year
            month=cal.selection_get().month
            day=cal.selection_get().day
            #~ tkMessageBox.askyesno("Date Select", cal.selection_get())
            root.withdraw()
            result = tkMessageBox.askyesno("Date Select", cal.selection_get())
            if result == True:
                root.destroy()

        top = tk.Toplevel(root)

        cal = Calendar(top, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day', locale='en_US',
                       cursor="hand1", year=datetime.date.today().year, month=datetime.date.today().month, day=datetime.date.today().day)

        cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        ttk.Button(top, text="select", command=print_sel).pack()



    root = tk.Tk()
    ttk.Button(root, text=myinput, command=example1).pack(padx=10, pady=10)




    root.mainloop()

    return year,month,day
```

Comment: Have you examined the value of `date` immediately before calling `e.insert`? If the date has a value, it definitely will be inserted in `e`.

Comment: Yes, it has a value (the selected date),                          but it is not insered in e .....

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me when I create a `select_date` that returns three values.

Comment: The code doesn't work when the select_date is a tkinter gui application. However select_date returns correctly the date (it simply doesn't writes it in the entrybox). I provide now in the question the select_date function.

Comment: The fact that you're creating a separate root window in the other function is a critical piece of information. Tkinter isn't designed to have two root windows (well, it sort-of is, but you have to know what you're doing and have to understand the ramifications).

Comment: If you put a print statement immediately after calling `select_date`, you'll see that the function never returns, so I don't know how it is possible for you to say that `date` has the selected date.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and the information! The date is printed in the terminal only after I kill the tkinter window.